# Radix sort on strings causes Python to be idle for three seconds and then crashes

Tags: python, sorting, crash, radix-sort

I am trying to apply Radix sort on a string of capital letters by iterating through each index and then iterating through each character at the index, determining which bucket to put it in.

The code I used for the sorting algorithm,

```
 
def radixsort(li, maxistrlen):
    for index in range(maxistrlen):
        buckets = [[]]*26
        for item in li:
            try: bucket = ord(item[index]) - 65  # All characters are uppercase.
            except IndexError: bucket = 0
            buckets[bucket].append(item)
        li = sum(buckets, [])  # Flat the list out.
    return li

print(radixsort(['ABC', 'ABD', 'ACQ', 'QRV', 'ZIY', 'BLC', 'AAI'], 3))
```

took over three seconds to run and then crashed Python when the output was being  printed.

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong in my algorithm implementation.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your program works fine here. It produces a lot of output, but it completes in less than a second. Is you computer short of memory or some other resource?

Comment: Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see what it's doing?

Comment: Somebody please write a complete answer... I can't deal with answering this same exact question 5 times a day. (Hint: `[[]]*26`)

Comment: Well, I ran it in IDLE at it hang for ten seconds before finally crashing

Comment: ...Nobody? Sigh. Try `buckets = [[] for _ in range(26)]` instead of `buckets = [[]]*26`.

Comment: That doesn't work.